# Windows flash player

Tags: flash

I have a game that requires windows flash for Firefox to play, I installed flash for Firefox 17 but when I check version it says Linux 11 still and game cant detect it so how can I get the game to detect the windows flash player?

Comment: The flash player required to play is the windows 7 Fp for firefox 17

Comment: The game requirments are very specific, is says i have to have the flash for firefox installed and linux does nto have flash for firefox option on adobe it runs with windows does nto have linux capabilities

Comment: so far with wine ive got the game to launch but while ingame it says flash not detected so i need to find a way to get the windows flash for firefox i installed to be activ and detectable

Comment: I know there is a way to get it to run, if i can get windows programs to run with win then it should be no problem to get this flash player to run. need info

Answer (score 5):

So that you may retain your ubuntu specific firefox and flashplugin installation for purposes other than running that particular game, I suggest you install the windows version of firefox and adobe flashplugin using wine. To do this, run the following commands in an open terminal:

```
mkdir FF; cd FF
sudo apt-get update
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/37.0.2/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2037.0.2.exe
sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar
7z e Fire*
```

It may ask you if you would like to overwrite a file; press <kbd>u</kbd> to rename the file and then run the following commands:

```
wine setup.exe
```

accept the basic options but decline to "make firefox your default browser" and keep the option to "automatically start firefox" at the end. After firefox starts up for the first time, close firefox.

Next, run the following commands to install adobe flash on your windows version of firefox:

```
wget https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/17.0.0.169/install_flash_player.exe
wine install_flash_player.exe
```

follow the instructions accepting the default options and accept the licensing agreement if the installer asks you to do so.

There should be a firefox icon on your desktop, click the icon to run the windows version of firefox and don't forget to go to settings > addons > plugins to enable the flashplugin.

Comment: I did all camands but the add on screen is blank

Comment: flash player still not detected, the get addon for firefox isnt even listing adobe flash player

Comment: ive googled it but nothing is explaining why adobe flash player is no longer in the add on page, you cant add it or anything

Comment: what im saying is the last part where you say plugins enable, well theres nothing on the list to enable even after installing it with the camands

Comment: @JeffreyKoger click on addons and **then** go to **plugins** , you will find the option to enable or disable the adobe flash **plugin** under the **plugins** tab. You couldn't find anything on Google about why it's not there because it **is still there** it's listed under **plugins** and not with the other addons. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/) to install the windows version of Flash. It will co-exist with your linux version so you can choose depending on your needs which to use.

Instructions on the website are very clear and easy to follow.

Pipelight also makes other plugins like Unity and Silverlight (and more) available to Linux users.

Comment: I should mention that on my setup I have a problem with the 'coexistence' - firefox will disable / enable BOTH plugins, which means only the newest (windows) version is actually used. Didn't figure out yet if this is a problem with pipelight or firefox.